# Suppress section numberrs in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

I am creating a file, where the section headings should have box around the number. Also, some sections should not display this number even though the box should still be there. To solve this, I created two environments using titlesec, where in one environment the number has a different color than the box fill color, while in the other the colors match.

The problem I have is that both section numbers are displayed in the TOC. I looked up titlesec documentation and it mentioned something about using the \ifthesection condition to suppress numbers in TOC, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

I am attaching an example, with some dummy sections and the environments. I don't want the number for Exercises A (section 0.2) to be displayed. Can someone help me out on this?

Thank you,

Raman

[image: Screenshot of current output]

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,hidelinks]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage[ paper=a4paper,  layoutheight = 8.2in, layoutwidth  = 6in, layoutvoffset= 35mm, layouthoffset = 29mm, margin=0pt, includeheadfoot, showcrop=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\sectionbar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=2.1cm,trim right=2.0cm] {
    %               \fill [black] (2.0cm,-0.3ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,-0.1ex);
    \node [
    fill=lightgray,
    anchor= base east,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=3.5ex, minimum width=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        %                   \color{white} \textbf{\arabic{\section}}
        \color{white}   \textbf{\thesection}
    };
    \fill [black] (\textwidth-13.15cm,-0.9ex) rectangle (\textwidth+2.1cm,-1.1ex);      
}%
}
 \titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\sectionbar}{1.5cm}{}

\newcommand\exercisebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=2.1cm,trim right=2.0cm] {
    %               \fill [black] (2.0cm,-0.3ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,-0.1ex);
    \node [
    fill=lightgray,
    anchor= base east,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=3.5ex, minimum width=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        %                   \color{white} \textbf{\arabic{\section}}
        \color{lightgray}   \textbf{\thesection}
    };
    \fill [black] (\textwidth-13.15cm,-0.9ex) rectangle (\textwidth+2.1cm,-1.1ex);      
}%
}

\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\exercisebar}{1.5cm}{}
%   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}%
%   \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}
    }
{%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
   }
  \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \section {LEARNING OBJECTIVES}
 \blindtext \\
  \lipsum[1]

 \begin{exercises}
 \section{Exercises A}
 \blindtext
 \lipsum[2-3]
 \end{exercises}


 \section{Exercises B}
 \blindtext
 \lipsum[4-5]


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the most worst solution:

```
\newenvironment{exercises}{%
    \titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\exercisebar}{1.5cm}{}
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
         \string\let\string\oldnumberline\string\numberline%
         \string\renewcommand\string\numberline\string[1]\string\oldnumberline{\strut}}%
    }%  
 }{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
         \string\let\string\numberline\string\oldnumberline%
    }
}
```